# TypeError: wrong argument type class (expected module) in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

i'm developing a simple net application (packed as a gem) to learn Ruby and TDD.
I have this class (receiver.rb):

```
require 'eventmachine'
class Receiver < EM::Connection
    def initialize(port)
        EM.run do
            EM.open_datagram_socket('0.0.0.0', port, self)
        end
    end
end
```

And this test (receiver_spec.rb):

```
require "spec_helper"
require "net/receiver"

describe "Receiver" do
    it "can istantiate" do
        @rec = Receiver.new(500)
    end
end
```

Anyway, when i run `rspec` it prints out this:

```
1) Receiver can istantiate
     Failure/Error: @rec = Receiver.new(500)
     TypeError:
       wrong argument type Receiver (expected Module)
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-     1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1535:in `include'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1535:in `block in klass_from_handler'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1535:in `initialize'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1535:in `new'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1535:in `klass_from_handler'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine- 1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:867:in `open_datagram_socket'
     # ./lib/rppc/net/receiver.rb:9:in `block in initialize'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
     # /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
     # ./lib/rppc/net/receiver.rb:8:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/net/receiver_spec.rb:6:in `new'
     # ./spec/net/receiver_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm quite new to the ruby environment, so if i missed something let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what documentation you're working from, but it appears the `open_datagram_socket` requires a `Module` and cannot accept a `Class` as the third (handler) argument.

Per the comment in http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine.open_datagram_socket, it appears this restriction may have been loosened in a later version of `EventMachine`

Comment: [here](https://parroty00.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/eventmachine-udp-server-example/) it uses a class